# How to mention a user when using @tasks.loop() in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I have been recently coding a task loop which I would like to mention a user when executing the loop. As you cannot pass ctx as a parameter in the code below:

```
@tasks.loop(seconds=120)
async def nameHere():
```

I have become unsure how would I would get around this. I have also tried starting the loop by using a command (example below):

```
@client.command()
async def start(ctx):
  nameHere.start(ctx)
```

While this does work this is not my plan. I want to start the task.loop automatically and when it starts it should mention the member who has sent a message in the channel. But without having access to any `ctx` or `message` parameters I am unsure what to do (it would generate the error if I tried to use the message parameter `nameHere() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'` and setting it to None causes a NoneType error)

Answer (score 0):

Create a class `commands.Cog` and add your variable `ctx` and your `task` to it.

```py
from discord.ext import tasks, commands


class MyCogTask(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, ctx: commands.Context):
        self.ctx = ctx

    @tasks.loop(seconds=120)
    async def mention_loop():
        await self.ctx.channel.send(self.ctx.author.mention)
 

@client.command()
async def start(ctx: commands.Context):
    my_cog = MyCogTask(ctx)
    my_cog.mention_loop.start()
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your answer I appreciate it, I do have one question. Is it possible to have the task start automatically (with still using ctx parameters) without using a command?

Comment: Yes, but then you won't have a `ctx` parameter, since this is associated with the use of a command. You will need to pass the user id.
To start automatically, you can use the [on_ready](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.event) event.

Comment: I understand. However I cannot pass the user ID in the on_ready event as I had plans for the bot to mention the first user who sent a message in a channel and that could be anyone, is it possible to that? Also I appreciate your help :)

Comment: So, you can use the `on_message` event to capture the first message from the channel.

Comment: I will try that and see what happens. Again I really appreciate it